# How to execute spring core code through TestNG from mac terminal

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, testng

I stuck and have been searching forever. Can someone show me how to execute the test case below from a mac terminal? It is from a maven project if that matters. I'm using Spring Tool Suite & included a screenshot.

Please provide the command line syntax I need to use.

```
package com.spring.ioc.DependencyInjection;

import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TestNgApp {

    @Test
    public void main() throws Exception {

        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("app-config.xml");

        try {

            TextEditor te = (TextEditor) context.getBean("textEditor");
            te.spellCheck();

        } finally {
            context.close();
        }

    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: `mvn package` will build your project and run your tests.

Comment: @tgdavies Example?

Comment: Change in to the directory containing your project and type `mvn package`.

Comment: @tgdavies Damn. So simple. That worked. Thanks.